# Google spreadsheets Query Language get data from many other sheet

Tags: google-docs, google-apps, google-apps-script

How I can get data from many sheets? In documentation [Reference data from other sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75943&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=-1qyjxl0cyc7v6&cbrank=4) is an example

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

I wrote test query and it's works

```
=Query(otherSheet!A1:P999, "select A, B, C")
```

But I want get data with one query from many tables. is it possible? How I can?

---UPDATE---

For example I have 2 sheet as `clients` and `orders`, and I want get username who buy some product last month. I found solutions, for example I get `cient_id` from `order table`, and then I get `username` from `clients` table

```
=Unique(Query(orders!A1:P999, "select D WHERE I = 'paid' and J > date '2010-01-15' LABEL D 'client_id' "))

=vlookup(A2,contacts!B:C,2,false)
```

You can write it with single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be more specific to be able to get a good answer, but I will try to give you the directions that I can think of.

You can join your data physically and create a single sheet with all the data. You don't have neither to copy the data nor refer it (using `=`), as you can use `EXPAND` function:

```
=EXPAND(SORT(Sheet1!A:C))
```

Another option is to join the criteria that you want to have on each sheet using `ARRAYFORMULA`; something like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((SheetX!A2:C3>5)*(SheetY!A2:C3="Category A")*(A2:C3))
```

--- UPDATED ---

For your updated function try something like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(
  (orders!I:I="paid")*(orders!J:J>"2010-01-15")*(orders!D:D),
  contacts!B:C,2
 ))
```

You can add the `UNIQUE` function as well right inside the `VLOOKUP`, as well as other functions as `SORT`.

Note that you can also replace the values of the query ("2010-01-15", for example) with values in cells (=E2, for example), instead of having hardcoded values in the function.